# Open new window in infobox Shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

Here's a simple one (i'm um a hurry):

I have this infobox and i need the `href` to open a new window.

```
infoBox("value","info", icon = icon("user"), href = "http://url.com")))
```

is there and argument to do so?
because the way it is now it opens in the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to open a new window is to [set the target of a link to `"_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target). You can do that in JavaScript [using the second parameter of the window.open method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), i.e.: `window.open(url, target)`. You can run JavaScript from a link by using the `javascript:` protocol. Putting it all together:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

newTabLink <- "javascript:void(window.open('https://google.com', '_blank'))"
ui <- fluidPage(
    infoBox("value", "info", icon = icon("user"), href = newTabLink)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(Wrapping the JavaScript in `void(...)` is a usual best practice when putting JavaScript in a link, but it may be unnecessary here.)

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot!